# Background script execution in web - Katalon

Tags: katalon

we are using katalon studio version 7.8.

We have initiated the script execution and proceeded with other works by accessing File explorer for example.

Script execution is getting stopped and throwing an error “Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000”

If focus is moved again to the browser, script execution continues.

Can you share the solution why background execution is getting stopped.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a headless mode (of Chrome, for example)?

Comment: No we have not tried with headless but our requirement is to execute the scripts only in Chrome UI.  Kindly suggest some solutions for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [headless mode](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/headless-browsers-execution.html#configuring-headless-browsers) for Chrome.

You can set the headless mode programmatically with

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions

import com.kms.katalon.core.configuration.RunConfiguration
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", DriverFactory.getChromeDriverPath())
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions()
opt.addArgument('headless')
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt)
DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver)
WebUI.navigateToUrl('www.katalon.com')
```